# electron - allowing access to webcam

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, electron

In orden to use webcam from my `electron` app I installed `webcamjs` node module, this is the code I've used,  taken from module docs:

```
<h1>camara</h1>
<div id="my_camera" style="width:320px; height:240px;"></div>
<div id="my_result"></div>

<script language="JavaScript">
Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
function take_snapshot() {
Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
    document.getElementById('my_result').innerHTML = '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
} );
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(take_snapshot())">Take Snapshot</a>
```

When I try to access the webcam, electron throws me the following exception:

> *Uncaught ReferenceError: take_snapshot is not defined*.

However, when I test the same code from `Firefox`, it works well. Firefox announces that tries to access the webcam and given OK to complete the action. Moreover, from `Chrome` seems that this is not allowed because he tells me:

> *Webcam.js error: Webcam is not loaded yet.*

I know that it need a SSL to work in Chrome, but electron support it?
So, any suggestions to use the camera from `electron`?

Answer (score 4):

Try this one

```
navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false}, (localMediaStream) => {
        var video = document.querySelector('video')
        video.srcObject = localMediaStream
        video.autoplay = true
     }, (e) => {})
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an external library in order to capture your webcam stream.

In your HTML page:

```
<video id="video" height="480" width="800" autoplay></video>
```

In your JavaScript file:

```
const constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
        mandatory: {
            maxHeight: 480,
            maxWidth: 800,
            minHeight: 480,
            minWidth: 800,
        }
    }
};

const videoElement = document.getElementById('video');

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
navigator.getUserMedia(
    constraints,
    stream => videoElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream),
    error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: getting DOMException: Could not start video source in my app, when it is packaged.